# Interface 'FunctionMatchers<Fn>' incorrectly extends interface 'Matchers<any>'

Tags: angular

i use ngx-admin-starter, and updated to angular 11, and then this error appear

[image]

i have tried changing the `@types/jasmine` version but the error still appearing.

i also have tried changing the `typescript`, currently its on 4 but still the error appearing.

here's my dependencies

```
"@angular/cdk": "^11.2.12",
"@angular/common": "^11.2.13",
"@angular/compiler": "^11.2.13",
"@angular/core": "^11.2.13",
"@types/angular": "^1.8.1",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.7.2",
"@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
v"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
```

does anyone have any  idea why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So after couple hours researching and trying other solutions, i remove the `@types/jasmine` and install `@types/jasminewd2@latest` and it's working now

Comment: Saved me tons! Thanks!

Comment: glad you find it helpful!

Comment: npm install @types/jasminewd2@latest